# flex custom event with item renderer and custom component

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer, custom-events

OK you Flex experts, I need some help. I have a datagrid in my main application with an itemrenderer (mxml). When you press the image in the ir, a custom component (mxml) opens. The cc has a button that is supposed to call a function in the main application which updates the arraycollection (dataprovider) and therefore the datagrid updates. I've tried several variations of parentDocument, outerDocument, and custom events, but I cannot get that function to work from the button. I think it's b/c I have the cc nested in the ir. Anything that I call directly from within the ir works.

Does anyone have any suggestions or even better a working example I could take a look at?

Here's what I tried:

//in main application

```
public function creationComplete_handler(event:FlexEvent):void{
   dgList.addEventListener("ceRD", fnt_ceRD);
}
public function fnt_ceRD():void {
    Alert.show("called");
}


<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="dgList" dataProvider="{acLists}" designViewDataType="flat">
   <mx:columns>
      <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Roster" sortable="false" itemRenderer="c_CO.AppLocal.ListManager.iRenderers.irADVStudents" />   </mx:columns>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

In itemrenderer, used the popupmanager so that I could center on top of application as opposed to button in datagrid

```
public function btnRoster(event:MouseEvent):void{
    var rShow:rosterDetails = new rosterDetails();
    PopUpManager.addPopUp(rShow, FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.mainContent, true);
    PopUpManager.centerPopUp(rShow);
}
```

In custom component:

```
 <fx:Metadata>
        [Event("ceRD", true, false)]
    </fx:Metadata>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        import flash.events.Event;

            protected function btnSave(event:MouseEvent):void {

            var i_ceRD:Event = new Event("ceRD");
            dispatchEvent(i_ceRD);
            PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);

        }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried please?  In most cases I recommend using a custom event in the renderer [make sure the bubbles property is set to true]; then add a listener on the DataGrid for the event [you can do so in the DataGrid's initialize event]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are experiencing trouble because the listener for "ceRD" is added to the DataGrid while the event is being dispatched from the Roster Details component. There is no relationship between the DataGrid and RosterDetails.

Consider moving the logic to create and display the `RosterDetails` out of the ItemRenderer. I would suggest having the `irADVStudents` renderer dispatch an 'imageClick' event which can be handled in your main application.

Inline renderers are helpful for adding simple event handling:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid dataProvider="{acLists}">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Roster" sortable="false">
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <mx:Component>
                    <local:irADVStudents imageClick="outerDocument.onRoster(event)"/>
                </mx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

Then you can simply add a listener for your 'save' event. Ensure to remove the listener as this is a potential memory leak. (A weak listener is also an option).

```
public function onRoster(event : Event) : void
{
    var rosterDetails : RosterDetails = new RosterDetails();
    rosterDetails.addEventListener("save", onSave);

    PopUpManager.addPopUp(rosterDetails, this, true);
    PopUpManager.centerPopUp(rosterDetails);
}

protected function onSave(event:Event):void
{
    Alert.show("SAVED");
}
```

Custom events can be used to pass data around the application, such as which item was clicked on from the renderer.

Comment: I took your advice and remove the formal mxml itemrenderer and just used a straight image tag where the click event handler called a function through outerDocument. Then I added the custom component which now was owned by the top level app. This allowed me to add a custom event in the component. All is well with the universe again. Thanks to your suggestions and help!!!